# KNP Doctrinebehaviors Bundle : how to show translatable entity?

Tags: symfony

I use KNP Doctrinebehaviors Bundle to translate my entity, and a2lix_translations to get i18n form,

I have no problems with those steps :

- Adding entity with multi-languages.
- Getting entities in cases my default locale language.
- Update entity.
- Delete entity.

But the probleme is how to access the propreties of my Page Entity in twig?

This is somes pictures to understand the problem :

This is my PageEntity

```js
public function findAllByLocale($locale){

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                   ->join('a.translations', 'aTrans')
                   ->where('aTrans.locale = :locale')
                   ->setParameter("locale", $locale)
                   ->addSelect('aTrans')
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult()
        ;        
    }
```

```html
use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;
    

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="trans", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $object;
    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        if( $title == $this->translate()->getTitle() ) {
        return $title;
    }
    return '';
    }
    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
    /**
     * @param $method
     * @param $args
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (!method_exists(self::getTranslationEntityClass(), $method)) {
            $method = 'get' . ucfirst($method);
        }

        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $args);
    }

and this is my query : 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
```

[FormType](http://snapplr.com/snap/1gtw)
[twig page : index.html.twig](http://snapplr.com/snap/xsbm)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to what I understood:

**FIRST:**
If you want to display the translated fields of an entity based on guessed locale, from the [doc](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#proxy-translations):

> proxy translations
>   An extra feature allows you to proxy translated fields of a translatable entity.
>   You can use it in the magic __call method of you translatable entity so that when you try to call getName (for example) it will return you the translated value of the name for current locale:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments)
{
    return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
}
```

Now when displaying an entity that has a translated field `name` in a twig template you can use:

```
{{ entity.getName() }}
```

The proxy will intercept your call and return the appropriate content by guessing the locale from the request. This is how you'll want to display most entities.

**SECOND:**
The other way if you specifically want to translate an entity in French then you can use the following, also in twig:

```
{{ entity.translate('fr').getName() }}
```